# Why is the navbar not stretching to the right?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a Bootstrap page with a navbar like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <div class="container-fluid sts-screen-fluid">
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-nav navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <span class="navbar-brand">Kn</span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Help</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You see, the problem is that my Navbar does not seem to stretch all the way towards the right, so it looks like this:

[image: that navbar is trying to pull a lefty!]

What should I do to get the navbar get to the right?

Comment: p.s. I have not applied any extra css

Comment: Is there any rule for the `.sts-screen-fluid` class?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 0):

That is because You have `container` div in `container-fluid` div.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `container-fluid` to `container`.

Comment: that doesn't work. can you show me a fiddle or a codepen or something?

Comment: Just copy one of the bootstrap examples: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k9ev1vuc/).

```
<div class="container-fluid sts-screen-fluid">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="navbar-brand">Kn</span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `.navbar` class instead of `.navbar-nav` in the `<nav>` tag. The `.navbar-nav` class is used for the `<ul>` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid sts-screen-fluid">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="navbar-brand">Kn</span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [bootstrap's documentation (Source: w3school)](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h) , `.container-fluid`
class should be inside `.navbar .navbar-inverse`.

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
       </nav>
```

[Demo from Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h)